# Передать параметры в тест

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Есть фикстура:

```
@pytest.fixture
def fixture():
    a = 1
    # Before
    yield
    # After
```

Есть тест:

```
def test_1():
    # define a
    assert a == 1
```

Как передать в тест параметр `a` из фикстуры? Я понимаю, что можно использовать глобальные переменные, но это не очень удобный способ.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю вопрос. Вы хотите сделать так?: https://pastebin.com/ZQpfvsQE

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы значение `a`, которое было объявлено в fixture, я подцепил в `test_1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yield может возвращать значение, которое будет передано в параметре теста, который называется, так же как и фикстура:

```
@pytest.fixture
def fixture():
    a = 1
    # Before
    yield a
    # After

def test_1(fixture):
    assert fixture == 1
```

Если нужно передать несколько значений, то можно вернуть произвольный объект, например, кортеж и потом из него достать значения. Вот пример использования кортежа для этой цели:

```
@pytest.fixture
def fixture():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    # Before
    yield (a, b)
    # After

def test_1(fixture):
    a, b = fixture
    assert a == 1
    assert b == 1
```